# Python and Selenium - Any suggection about what this code is doing

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I´m trying to figure out what this code is doing. It´s my new job and I have no one to ask, the last automation Qa changed projects and i have no contact with him. This is what i´m trying to understand, its pretty clear but the .location() part i don´t get:

```
    WebDriverWait(self.selenium,self.timeout).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(self._check_out_button))
    chk_button = self.selenium.find_element(*self._check_out_button)
    if self.browser == "CHROME":
        y = chk_button.location["y"]
        self.selenium.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(y) + ");")
    WebDriverWait(self.selenium, self.timeout).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(self._check_out_button))
    chk_button.click()
```

i don´t understand what the location("y") it´s doing.

That´s all

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `ypos` since `scrollTo()` scrolls to the `element` according to the coordinates, you need the `x` and `y` axis respectively. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp). And, `y = chk_button.location["y"]` line pretty much finding the `y` axis of **chk_button**

Comment: Glad it answers your question

Answer (score 2):

chk_button is a WebElement object.  The location method returns the element's location, and in this case you're specifically looking at the y coordinate

[See here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)